# Why does using SUM(mycolumn) suddenly make mycolumn non-existent

Tags: android, sqlite

I get an `IllegalArgumentException` when I try to use the aggregate function `SUM()` in my query which otherwise works fine without it.

Without using `SUM()` my `colPayDue` is referenced properly and I get the proper results but the moment I try to integrate a `SUM()` in the query it suddenly can't be found. I'm obviously doing something wrong but what?

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

```
    Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT  " + " _id, " + colCompClass + "," + colName + ", SUM(" + colPayDue + ")," + colDateDue + " FROM " + viewComps + " WHERE " + colDateDue + "=" + "( SELECT MIN (" + colDateDue + ") FROM " + viewComps + " WHERE " + colDateDue + ">=?)" + " GROUP BY " + colDateDue + "," + colCompClass, params);
```

Comment: change `SUM(" + colPayDue + ")` to `SUM(" + colPayDue + ")  as colPayDue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of query's output column normally is the expression that you have written in the SELECT clause.

So for this query:

```
SELECT _id,
       Name,
       SUM(PayDue)
FROM ...
```

the three output columns are named `_id`, `Name`, and `SUM(PayDue)`.

If you want to give another name to an expression, use AS:

```
SELECT _id,
       Name,
       SUM(PayDue) AS PayDue
FROM ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the explenation, although @Giru Bhai pretty much said the same thing seeing as he didn't post it as an answer I'll just leave an upvote on his comment and accept this in the meantime.